# Using ExportVolumeBlock from Kinect Fusion SDK

Tags: c++, kinect

I'm playing around with the newly released Kinect Fusion SDK. Now I'm pretty new to C++ coming from Objective-C and I'm having difficulties interpreting the 'Documentation' of some of the new functions.

[ExportVolumeBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.nuikinectfusionvolume.inuifusionreconstruction.exportvolumeblock.aspx) is the function I'm trying to use to isolate part of a volume (the face).

```
public:
HRESULT ExportVolumeBlock(
     UINT sourceOriginX,
     UINT sourceOriginY,
     UINT sourceOriginZ,
     UINT destinationResolutionX,
     UINT destinationResolutionY,
     UINT destinationResolutionZ,
     UINT voxelStep,
     UINT cbVolumeBlock,
     SHORT *pVolumeBlock
)
```

Now the ones I'm not quite sure about are cbVolumeBlock and pVolumeBlock.
Especially the last one states you need to pre-allocate a SHORT and ExportVolumeBlock expects a SHORT. However the documentation states *To access the voxel located at x,y,z use pVolume[z][y][x]*
But if I pre-allocate a 3D Short like

```
SHORT m_pVolumeB[30][30][30];
m_pVolume->ExportVolumeBlock(0, 0, 0, 30, 30, 30, 1, 8, m_pVolumeB);
```

I get the message:

> Error: argument of type "SHORT (*)[30][30]" is incompatible with
> parameter of type "SHORT *"

Working with a 1D SHORT I do get some results in it, but I'm not sure if that is the correct way of doing it. Does anyone have more experience with this function?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you must use a 1D array, then to read it for `(x,y,z)` if the volume is this size: `(xres,yres,zres)`:

```
int pitch = xres;
int slice = yres * pitch;
int index = (z * slice) + (y * pitch) + x;
```

Based on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.nuikinectfusionvolume.inuifusionreconstruction.exportvolumeblock.aspx